# How to use addLink() in PyPDF2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

```
addLink(pagenum, pagedest, rect, border=None, fit='/Fit', *args)
```

**Parameters:**

pagenum (int) – index of the page on which to place the link.

pagedest (int) – index of the page to which the link should go.

rect – RectangleObject or array of four integers specifying the clickable rectangular area [xLL, yLL, xUR, yUR], or string in the form "[ xLL yLL xUR yUR ]".

border – if provided, an array describing border-drawing properties. See the PDF spec for details. No border will be drawn if this argument is omitted.

fit (str) – Page fit or ‘zoom’ option (see below). Additional arguments may need to be supplied. Passing None will be read as a null value for that coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

`addLink(0, 1, [0, 20, 100, 120], "dott")`

`0` -> Page Number

`1` -> Destingion Page Number

`[0, 20, 100, 120]` -> rectangular area

`dott` -> Border

Comment: is "dott" used here to omit a border? That's what's happening when I enter it. When I try to omit border or have border= None, a black border actually shows up.